# PostAsync never returns in console application

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am trying to implement a simple XML HTTP POST interface, but somehow it just stops working. This is my code:

```
    HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Login("", "");
    }

    public async void Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var response = await SendXml("<foo>");
    }

    public async Task<string> SendXml(string xml)
    {
        var content = new StringContent(xml);
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8080/Path", content);
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseBody;
    }
```

Pretty simple I'd say, but when running, it just stops at `PostAsync`. When I put a breakpoint at the `ReadAsStringAsync`, it is never hit.

I get no exception, no error nothing. My server says "connection aborted while sending data".

I must be doing something simple wrong, but I cannot find it ... I must say the `await` stuff still confuses me a little bit. This code is a console application, could async/await cause issues here?

Comment: Async/await is not the cause of the problem. Have you tried specifying a timeout? Are you calling Task.Result anywhere in your calling code?

Comment: @Silvermind it might not be the cause, but when I remove it and use `.Result`, it works fine...

Comment: Don't use `.Result`, because that can cause deadlocks.

Comment: Are you using `[StaThread]`?

Comment: @Silvermind could it be that the console application ends before a result has been received? How would I wait for that?

Comment: Can you include that code?

Comment: @Silvermind I added some more code. I added `[STAThread]` to main, but main never awaits anything.

Comment: Don't use `[STAThread]`. I asked it because when using that, you can potentially get deadlocks, because some tasks might want to spawn on other threads and when it is not allowed, it can also cause deadlocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using Task based operations, you need to make your application async all the way down to the entry point of the application which is usually `Program.Main()`

If you are using C# >= 7.1 you can use [MainAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main)

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        private readonly static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        
        public async static Task Main()
        {
            var response = await SendXml("myxml");
        }

        public async static Task<string> SendXml(string xml)
        {
            var content = new StringContent(xml);
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8080/Path", content);
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return responseBody;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using an older version then an async entry point is not supported, but you can write:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        private readonly static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                // TODO: log unhandled exception
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static Task MainAsync()
        {
            var response = await SendXml("myxml");
        }

        public async static Task<string> SendXml(string xml)
        {
            var content = new StringContent(xml);
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8080/Path", content);
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return responseBody;
        }
    }
}
```

In this last case make sure you only have one single point where you call `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and not anywhere else, because that can cause deadlocks.

Comment: Thee is no point in `catch (Exception) { throw; }` as it’s the same as not catching at all if you just rethrow it.

Comment: @ckuri I know. I put it there on purpose as a guide to the op.